# List items styling

Tags: list, css

I'm having difficulties with a few css items on my website.
It all comes down to list items!

I have a menu bar that works using `<ul> <li>` and `<ol>` tags with their own css file, I have a slider that works on `<li>` from another css file and then some site content that has its own css file - but they all seem to be overwriting each other and hiding other items!

Has anyone got any tips on how to keep all these separate or how to stop this from occurring?

Here is an example of the menu css that seems to be changing everything:
http://pastebin.com/8Jd2XUUT
and the core menu css:
http://pastebin.com/eVsRvxs5
menu html: http://pastebin.com/P7Qh0M8a main sites css: http://pastebin.com/kKqP0N1C

Comment: If you don't put your code here or on jsfiddle.net, all we can do it's praying.

Comment: You should check your page with firebug (or inspector in WebKit) to see the rule overrides.
Then you can understand where you can modify your inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: It'd help a lot to see the HTML, too. There's nothing particular in your two CSS files that would make one set of styles interfere with the other. They target entirely different classes for a start.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem. Your CSS files are overriding one another because you have a `<ul class="menu lblue slide">` which they both seem to target. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about [CSS specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/), and how to use classes and ids. These concepts will help you manage your CSS.

So in your HTML you could have:

```
<ul></ul>
<ul class="foo"></ul>
<ul class="foo" id="bar"></ul>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
/* This targets all ul elements */
ul {
    font-size: 2em;
}
/* This targets only ul elements with a class of foo. It's more specific (has a higher specificity) than the above */
ul.foo {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: aqua;
}
/* The ul with a class of foo and an id of bar gets both sets of styles, but as ID has a higher specificity than class, the font size will be bigger. */
ul#bar {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

---

**Edit:** Ah-ha, I see the problem! Your CSS files appear to target items in `<ul class="menu">` and `<ul class="lblue">` respectively. You have a `<ul class="menu lblue slide">`, which means both CSS files will be targeting the same ul and one will override the other. The result will be a complete mess.

You need to separate the two menus in the HTML and target them accordingly, e.g.

```
<ul class="menu"><!-- Put the menu HTML code here --></ul>
<ul class="lblue"><!-- Put the lblue HTML code here --></ul>
```

You also seem to have misunderstood the id attribute. You can only use an id once per page, and it cannot contain spaces. So `id="lblue li"` will not work at all. I'd suggest removing them for now!

Comment: My answer still stands: You have one `ul` element where `class="menu lblue slide"`. Then you have multiple CSS files targetting at least two of those classes. They will override one another, so you need to separate those, somehow. Try changing it to `class="menu"` to stop the lblue and slider classes affecting the menu. Then perhaps you should learn about CSS selectors and how they work on HTML elements.

Comment: it seems the lblue points to the theme for that menu bar so removing the lblue from the class tag left it as just plain text

Comment: OK, back to basics. Create a page with just the HTML+CSS+JS for the menu on there. Does that work correctly? Now, add the HTML, CSS and JS for the slider. Does that break things? If so, see if the classes collide (e.g. do they both use class="slide"?). Now add the HTML, CSS and JS for the other content you mentioned. Does that break things? If so, use the browser dev tools to help figure out why.

Comment: I've been battling this for a long time now and found the cause to the problem. if you look at the menu html file, there is a `</ul>` missing from the bottom which means the opening `<ul>` with the menu class is closed now and not conflicting with other things!

Answer (score 1):

Give your lists IDs and then target the IDs specifically. Since IDs must be unique, you can target one list without affecting another.

For example, with the following HTML:

```
<ol id="list1">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ol>
<ul id="list2">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

You could use the following CSS

```
#list1 li {
    color: red;
}
#list2 li {
    color: blue;
}
```

Which applies different colors to the list items of each list.

Comment: I am looking into this but I'm not to sure on how to use it in the menu css that seems to be causing all the problems. it has a lot of the `.lblue lu > ul > li` in the css that is confusing me big time!

Comment: You would give the lists unique IDs and then modify your CSS to use those IDs. If you edit your original question with your code I can update my answer to be more specific.

Comment: Well two issues with the code you've posted are that the IDs to many elements contain a space (they shouldn't have any) and that IDs have been re-used (they can only be used once per document).

Answer (score 0):

Learn Specificity rules http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

this will teach you about weights of id's and classes and combinations there of.

Also there is the order styles are applied to consider (at the same weight last wins)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give unique id

```
<ul id="id">
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
</ul>

#id li {
    color: xx;   also you can try color:xx!important;
}
```